# Nginx reverse proxy - Internal servers separated by trailing slash

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm a newbie at Nginx, and have been searching a lot for the right answer to my question, but couldn't find it; not because it is not there, but my newbie condition limits me to adapt a generic solution to my issue.

The situation is this:
I have a Mantis Bug Tracker in my private LAN (http://10.111.111.12).
On the other hand, i have an OwnCloud website also on my LAN (IP 10.111.111.5), with URL http://10.111.111.5/owncloud/.

What i want to do is to deploy a Nginx Reverse Proxy that handles all requests from Internet at publicdomain.com, and use trailing slash for each internal webserver. The desired result would be:

http://www.publicdomain.com/bugtracker -> redirects to http://10.111.111.12/index.php
http://www.publicdomain.com/cloud -> redirects to http://10.111.111.5/owncloud/ (note that "cloud" is preferred over "owncloud")

On the future, it is necessary to continue using trailing slash for other web servers to be deployed.

Questions are:
is this scenario possible? if so, is it enough with configuring nginx or I have to reconfigure internal web servers as well?

I really appreciate your help, by indicating me a possible solution or pointing me to the right direction on previous posts.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to achieve such configuration and it's commonly used when NGINX is acting as a reverse proxy. You can use this configuration as an inspiration for building your own:

```
upstream bugtracker {
  server 10.111.111.12;
}

upstream cloudupstream {
  server 10.111.111.5;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location /bugtracker/{
    proxy_pass http://bugtracker;
  }
  location /cloud/{
    proxy_pass http://cloudupstream/owncloud;
  }
}
```

What's happening over here is that nginx will be listening on port 80 and as soon as a request comes for path /bugtracker, it will automatically route the request to the upstream server mentioned above. Using this you can add as many upstream servers and location blocks as you want.
Reference: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Namam for your quick answer. However, it isn't working yet. It seems that "server" at upstream directive does not allow slash, like this:
`server 10.111.111.5/owncloud;`

If i used it, i obtained
`nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "10.111.111.5/owncloud" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:43`

I started with the first upstream bugtracker, only, and nginx.conf like this:

```
    upstream bugtracker {
        server 10.111.111.12;
    }

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
    }

    location /mstic{
        proxy_pass http://bugtracker;
    }
        
        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

After that, when accesing to my Nginx Reverse proxy http://10.111.111.10/mstic/ i obtain the following:
`Not Found The requested URL /mstic/ was not found on this server.`
and no further details on error or access logs.

Thanks a lot in advance for any extra help you could bring me.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make `/cloud` work. Also can you try adding a slash to bug tracker like this `proxy_pass http://bugtracker/;` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for your help Naman. This is the result of new tests following your new answer, by adding slash to both internal serves, like this:
 location /mstic/{
  proxy_pass http://bugtracker/;
Now it works! but images, css and other resources not showing... The error.log shows a lot of entries like this:
"/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory)
It seems that it looks these resources at Nginx server and not at internal servers...
Thanks again for your help

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to accept the above answer if you found it useful :)
Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088

Comment: The last help i'd need from you is to solve the resources not found issue. I'd really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I think that's a different issue altogether and requires proper logs from `error.log`. I recommend you to create a new question and then post your findings. I'd be glad to help you there.

Comment: Here is the new post i have just created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64020120/nginx-reverse-proxy-trying-to-resolve-locally-upstream-servers-resources